# cancel any event or listener for a DOM element but not including mine

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm building a chrome extension which sets the style to "none" of any element the user clicks, it looks like this:

```
function handleMouseOver(e) {
// Change the background color when the mouse hovers over an element
e.target.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
  // Reset the background color when the mouse leaves an element
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = ""; // Set it to an empty string to reset to default
}

function clicked(e) {
  console.log(e.target);

  // Remove the other event listeners
  document.removeEventListener("click", clicked);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
  var result = confirm("Do you want to remove this element?");

  if (result) {
    // If the user confirms, hide the clicked element
    e.target.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    // If the user cancels, reset the background color
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }

}

   async function toggleClickListener(varFromPopup) {
     if (varFromPopup === true) {
     document.addEventListener("click", clicked);
     document.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
     document.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
    } 
  }

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
  toggleClickListener(message.myVar);
  if(message.myVar === false){
  document.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
  document.removeEventListener("click", clicked);
  }
});
```

if the user clicks on a button on my popup, it would send a message to my main script, and then activate the eventListener for the clicked function, and it works fine, the problem is, if i use some methods like event.stopPropagation() or event.preventDefault(), to stop the button from being clicked before or after setting its style to none, it also prevents my "clicked" function to be called, so i couldn't find another way to cancel the actions of a dom element but not cancelling my function too!
i hope my explanation isn't confusing